# Python+Flask - Getting "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html" when deploying on render.com (works fine locally)

Tags: python, templates, flask, deployment, render.com

*This is my first attempt at deploying a web service*

I have been locally developing a flask application for the last 2 months, and have never had any trouble finding templates. When I try to access my web app after being deployed on render.com, it displays this message on the website

**Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application**

These are the logs that are displayed after the error occurs

\

```
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM  [2023-08-15 19:53:33,394] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM  Traceback (most recent call last):
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2529, in wsgi_app
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      response = self.full_dispatch_request()
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      rv = self.dispatch_request()
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/app/views.py", line 20, in home
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      return render_template('index.html')
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 146, in render_template
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      template = app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list)
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1081, in get_or_select_template
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      return self._load_template(name, globals)
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 126, in load
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 62, in get_source
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 98, in _get_source_fast
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      raise TemplateNotFound(template)
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM  jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM  127.0.0.1 - - [15/Aug/2023:19:53:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 265 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM  [2023-08-15 19:53:33,576] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM  Traceback (most recent call last):
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2529, in wsgi_app
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      response = self.full_dispatch_request()
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      rv = self.dispatch_request()
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/app/views.py", line 20, in home
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      return render_template('index.html')
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 146, in render_template
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      template = app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list)
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1081, in get_or_select_template
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      return self._load_template(name, globals)
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 126, in load
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 62, in get_source
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 98, in _get_source_fast
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM      raise TemplateNotFound(template)
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM  jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
Aug 15 03:53:33 PM  127.0.0.1 - - [15/Aug/2023:19:53:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 265 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM  [2023-08-15 19:53:39,371] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM  Traceback (most recent call last):
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2529, in wsgi_app
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM      response = self.full_dispatch_request()
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM      rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM      rv = self.dispatch_request()
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM      return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/app/views.py", line 20, in home
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM      return render_template('index.html')
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 146, in render_template
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM      template = app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list)
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1081, in get_or_select_template
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM      return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM      return self._load_template(name, globals)
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM      template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 126, in load
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM      source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 62, in get_source
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM      return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 98, in _get_source_fast
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM      raise TemplateNotFound(template)
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM  jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
Aug 15 03:53:39 PM  127.0.0.1 - - [15/Aug/2023:19:53:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 265 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

[image: This is the file structure of my project]

****init**.py**

```
load_dotenv()
app = Flask('__main__', static_folder='app/static', template_folder='app/templates')

from app import views
```

**views.py**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'] )
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**run.py**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: FYI: the image is my file structure. It works fine on my local computer but not when deployed.

Comment: Please, give the structure of the server files

Comment: @DiegoBorba Where do I find those? On render.com or in my project code? Sorry, I'm new to web hosting

Comment: Your app are in a git repository right?

Comment: @DiegoBorba Yes it is!

Comment: The image is from a clone of it?

Comment: @DiegoBorba The image is the file structure of the project in vscode.

Comment: I know but you are sure that the structure is the same that the git repository?

Comment: @DiegoBorba Yes it is. Render.com deploys directly from your latest commit (which is what the image is a picture of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I was trying to find my template folder using a relative path. It was required that I use an absolute path in order to find my template files

```
template_folder='app/templates'
```

to

```
template_folder='/pathtoapp/app/templates'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use absolute path for your project dictionary:

```
import os

static_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'app', 'static')
template_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'app', 'templates')

app = Flask('__main__', static_folder=static_folder, template_folder=template_folder)
```

Comment: Just tried this. Received the same error